# How to prevent the browser from seeing my keystrokes?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-event

My browser (chrome but I think it doesn't matter) receives events for keystrokes which are not intended for it. For example, I'm doing `alt+tab` in Mate and then I press `escape` (while still holding the `alt`). This has the intended effect of the alt+tab dialog disappearing without switching the window but also the unintended effect of the browser thinking I just pressed `escape` (which affects the web application I'm using).

Looking for related questions I found this:
[How do I prevent programs from sniffing keystrokes to su/gksu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36281/how-do-i-prevent-programs-from-sniffing-keystrokes-to-su-gksu)
but my case is a little different - I (kind of) trust the browser, I just don't want it to think that I've pressed a key.

Is this something I can configure in xorg or in mate?

Comment: If it's a currently active foreground application it will receive those keystrokes regardless, even if you're running Wayland. At least it feels like it.